# unreachable code detected on for loop

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2010

Tried finding similar from my problem but it seems there are too many unreachable code detected
my table consist of 4 rows and I tried this code

```
using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(myConnection))
{
    conn.Open();
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);
    int num = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
    MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand(query2, conn);
    MySqlDataReader reader = cmd1.ExecuteReader();

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        for (int a = 0; a <= num; a++)
        {
            List li = new List();
            li.linkLabel1.Text = reader["TitleAnime"].ToString();
            flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(li);
            // break;
        }
    }
    conn.Close();
}
```

but it gives me 16 values and thats too much then I tried putting break inside the for loop and I was able to achieve my goal and it gives me 4 values which is the same on my table but there seems to be an error called unreachable code detected..should I ignore it since I was able to get what I need? or is there another way for that

Comment: You don't need to read `num` from the database first. `while (reader.Read())` already reads all of the records for you. Either that, or your `query2` isn't doing what you think it's doing.

Comment: sorry for my mistakes.I'm trying to get the row count first and that value will be the length or limit of the loop..

Comment: string query = "SELECT COUNT(TitleAnime) FROM maindatabase.animelist;";
            string query2 = "SELECT TitleAnime FROM maindatabase.animelist";

Comment: The reason you're getting 16 instead of 4 is that you have a for() loop that runs 4 times for every Read. You can get rid of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you are doing one query too much there, and you are getting NxN results because of that first query and of that for loop.

Try something like this:

```
using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(myConnection))
{
    conn.Open();
    MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand(query2, conn);
    MySqlDataReader reader = cmd1.ExecuteReader();

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        List li = new List();
        li.linkLabel1.Text = reader["TitleAnime"].ToString();
        flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(li);
    }
    conn.Close();
}
```

If that does the job, consider in changing the name of the `query1` and `cmd1` to `query` and `cmd` since now you'll have only one of each

Comment: tnx this code helps so the reader actually automatic read the number of times without needing the loop

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple. You're running a for loop based on the number of entries you have in your database from the command object.

The read method will iterate four times if that's how many records you have in your database. Refer to this article for more information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.read(v=vs.110).aspx.

In short, just remove the for loop and you'll get the result you want.

Comment: one more question..if I'm gonna remove the for loop.how do i repeat the linklabels the number of times of equivalent on the number of entries in my database..can you give me some atleast skeletal codes for reference..

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    flowLayoutPanel1.Controls
        .Add(new List { linkLabel1.Text = reader["TitleAnime"].ToString()});
}
```

Comment: tnx gonna try this one too